# Seamless SQLServer Database Name Change

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, rename

I need to change the name for a few databases, however the databases are used by a lot of applications managed by several different teams. It would take some time for all the applications to finish changing connections and database name references. Is there a way to allow the change to be done seamlessly? Was looking at synonyms to temporarily allow references to the renamed database but unfortunately it is only for database level.

Comment: sorry I don't understand your question
"I need to change the name for a few databases"
"Was looking at synonyms to temporarily allow references to the renamed database but unfortunately it is only for database level"
aren't you contradicting yourself ?

Comment: Hi, sorry if it sounded confusing, by database level I means that it was only applicable for objects within the database and not the database itself. If it is server level, I could have a synonym to redirect old references to the renamed database temporarily.

Comment: can't you create a db with the name you want & then fill it with synonyms pointing to the objects you want to alias?

Comment: that makes sense, but then I would need to create synonyms to point to every object in the renamed database

Comment: @JieLong, yes, you would need to create synonyms for every object. I've used that technique for use cases other than a databases rename (e.g. a synonym database used to toggle between 2 different databases).

Comment: If you write a script against the system objects to create your synonyms it is quite quick

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create an "alias" database with the name you want to use.
Create synonyms for the objects by querying the system tables to create a simple script, here for example for user tables.

```
select 
  'Create Synonym '
   +quotename(object_schema_name(id, db_id()))+'.'
   +quotename(o.name)+
   ' For [SourceDB].'
   +quotename(object_schema_name(id, db_id()))+'.'
   +quotename(o.name)+';' 
from sysobjects o where type = 'U'
```